# Verb for the object `dareka` in `探さずにはいられない 誰かを`

Tags: translation

Here is part of the lyrics of Mai Kuraki's Time After Time:

```
風舞う花びらが
水面を撫でるように
大切に想うほど切なく…

人は皆 孤独と言うけれど
探さずにはいられない 誰かを
儚く壊れやすいものばかり
追い求めてしまう

Time after time
君と色づく街で
出逢えたらもう約束はいらない
誰よりもずっと傷付きやすい君の
そばにいたい今度はきっと
```

The full lyrics can be found [here](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a000616/l001d01.html), in case someone wants to see them. This passage I translate to:

```
The flower petals dancing in the wind
Seem to be stroking the water's surface
The more [I] believe [they] are important, the more [I] suffer…

Although all people say they are lonely (lit. "say «loneliness»")
[They look for] someone [they] can't depend on if [they] don't look for [them]
[But] only fragile and transient things
[They] end up pursuing

Time after time
If with you in the city of changing hues
[I] were to meet, [I] would never need promises
Of you, who are always easier to wound than anyone,
I want to stay at the side, this time, surely.
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. The main question is about `探さずにはいられない 誰かを`. Analyzing it, I see `sagasazu`, from `sagasu`, to look for, which is a negative connective form, so `not looking for`, then `ni`, stessing the "adverbial" nature of `sagasazu`, `wa`, marking the lot as a topic, `irarenai`, negative potential of `iru` (`要る`, I take it, but surely not `居る`), `to depend on`, `to need`, `dareka`, `someone`, and `wo`, marking `dareka` as object. So the translation should be:

   > someone (obj) from whom [they] cannot depend if without looking for [him/her]

   The question of course is: what is the verb holding this object? The subject is probably `mina` in the line above, as in the whole verse, meaning `everyone`.
2. Then we have this "water's surface", which has come out of nothing since I don't remember anything before or afterwards referring to water, so what water is it?
3. What is the subject of `大切に想うほど切なく…`?
4. Why do some translations refer the "always" to "I want to be" when `zutto` is in the middle of the relative clause `dare yori mo zutto kizutsuki yasui kimi`?
5. The `mono` in `koware yasui mono`, is it `者` (people) or `物` (things)?

Comment: We would still prefer if you asked one question per question when possible.  This is better than when you asked 7 questions in one about the same song, but it's still not quite ideal.

Comment: Also, ずっと often appears in comparative constructions.  See [よりもずっと on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E3%82%82%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8&ref=sa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

①　誰かを探す
何々せずにはいられない　～＝　何々しないではいられない　（＝居られない）

人は皆 孤独と言うけれど
They say we're all alone, but
探さずにはいられない 誰かを
I can't help but look... for someone

②　It's water in general; no context is needed.

③
風舞う花びらが
like petals dancing in the wind
水面を撫でるように
caressing the water's surface
大切に想うほど切なく…
the more precious **you** feel them, the more painful

④ Could be ambiguous
誰よりも **ずっと傷付きやすい** 君のそばにいたい今度はきっと
or
誰よりも **ずっと** 傷付きやすい君のそばに **いたい** 今度はきっと
though the former is probably more likely with this phrasing.

⑤ Either interpretation is probably ok; hence the かな.

Comment: So you are saying that the subject from `sagasazu` to `shimau` is always "I"? And how should I guess the subject in point 3 is you rather than I? Is that you meant to be sort of impersonal or is it the person the song addresses?

Comment: And one last comment: `iru` is used there in the potential form, so the construction literally means "I can't exist without ~ing".

Comment: @MickG ① ～～せずにはい(居)られない is a set phrase, meaning "can't help but do~~". The subject of 探さずにはいられない and 追い求めてしまう is "人(は皆)". It's saying 「『人というものは、皆、孤独なものだ。』と、(一般的に/よく)言うけれど、それでも、(人というものは)誰かを探さずにはいられないものだ。(人というものは)儚く壊れやすいものばかり追い求めてしまうものだ。」 ④ The ずっと means はるかに. (≒誰よりもはるかに傷つきやすい; way more sensitive; way more easily hurt than anyone) ⑤ It's 物, not 者. We might say 儚い人生 or 儚い(人の)命, but not 儚い者 or 儚い人.